# Error when installing Magento connect manager

Tags: magento, plugins

When I install some plugin via magento connect manager, it show some problem as follows:

```
WARNING: channel "connect.magentocommerce.com/community" has updated its protocols, use "channel-update connect.magentocommerce.com/community" to update 
downloading ZizioGroupSale-1.2.1.tgz ... 
Starting to download ZizioGroupSale-1.2.1.tgz (92,626 bytes) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ...done: 92,626 bytes
ERROR: failed to mkdir /home/onlyforc/public_html/app/code/community/Zizio/Groupsale/Block/Adminhtml
```

How to make it easier?

[image]

Comment: This looks to be a permissions problem. Make sure you have directories CHMOD'd to 755 and files set to 644 (may vary depending on server set up.) Also ensure apache has write permissions to the relevant directories

Comment: Just now I have attached a picture of the directories /home/onlyforc/public_html/app/code/community/.It is right? if not, how to modify it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What @sulman is referring to is the owner of the files/folders, not necessarily the permissions.  If you have command line access then you can do `chown -R apache:apache *` from the site root.  You can set the permissions to 777 temporarily in a pinch but be sure to change them back after you install the extension.